# Return chrome.storage.sync Items From Custom Method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, key, storage

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension using chrome.storage.sync, using the following object:

```
var storage = {
  "area":chrome.storage.sync,

  "get":function(key){

    var result = true,
      callback = function(items){
        result = items[key];
      };

    this.area.get(key,callback);

    return result;
  },

  "set":function(key,value){
    //create an empty object for a key:value pair
    var object = {};

    object[key] = value;

    console.log(object);

    this.area.set(object,function(){
     console.log(object);
    });

  }
};
```

But the "get" method never returns the result. It only returns "true" in this example. Why can't I get the actual value of the item, store it in result, and return it? Does it take time for Chrome to fetch the key:value pairs? If so, how do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `chrome.storage` operations are asynchronous, you should pass your callback function when calling the `get` method instead.

```
var storage = {
  "area":chrome.storage.sync,

  "get":function(key, callback){    
    this.area.get(key,callback);
  },

  "set":function(key,value){
    //create an empty object for a key:value pair
    var object = {};

    object[key] = value;

    console.log(object);

    this.area.set(object,function(){
     console.log(object);
    });

  }
};
```

Call it with:

```
var callback = function(items) {
    // get your object from chrome.storage here
    // and perform your actions.
    console.log(items);
}
storage.get(key, callback);
```